# DataSet help in C#

Tags: c#, database, dataset, datarow

I connected an sql database in c# and now trying to put the contents into a dataset. How will I be able to do that?

My code is:

```
string constr = "Data Source=ECEE;Initial Catalog=Internet_Bankaciligi;User ID=sa";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);

        SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Internet_Bankaciligi", conn);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        DataRow myDataRow;


        SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);


        mySqlDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet,"Internet_Bankaciligi");

        myDataRow = myDataSet.Tables["IB_Account"].NewRow();
        myDataRow["Account_ID"] = "NewID";
        myDataRow["Branch_ID"] = "New Branch";
        myDataRow["Amount"] = "New Amount";

        myDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows.Add(myDataRow);
```

the line: "mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet,"Internet_Bankaciligi");" gives an error as 'Invalid object name 'Internet_Bankaciligi'.' but Internet_Bankaciligi is my database name.

Also if i use:

```
SqlCommand selectCMD = new SqlCommand("select (*) from IB_Account", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCMD;

        myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
```

then: "SqlCommand selectCMD = new SqlCommand("select (*) from IB_Account", conn);" gives an error saying invalid syntax. How will I get it correct?

Answer (score 5):

If "`Internet_Bankaciligi`" is your actual database name, then you can't execute a SQL command directly against it.  You have to change your SQL to select from a table or a view.

Your second example doesn't work because "`SELECT (*)`" is not valid syntax.  It should be "`SELECT * FROM IB_Account`"... no parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this statement in Sql Server 2008:

```
Select (*) from <table>
```

It doesn't work. I never seen this syntax, not in sqlserver 2005, nor Oracle nor sqlite.

try this one:

```
Select * from <table>
```

---

**Edit:** If I were you I will try using *strongly typed datasets*, or even *Entity Framework* which both are more advance and easier to work with. Google them.